# sql_last_value in logstash is always 351

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I was working on inserting indexes to elasticsearch using logstash. My conf looks like this:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => ""
        jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => " com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        tracking_column => "time"
        use_column_value => true
        statement => "SELECT time, firstname, lastname, email FROM sample.sample where time > :sql_last_value;"
        schedule => " * * * * * *"
}
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
document_id=> "%{time}"
    document_type => "doc"
        "hosts" => ["myhost"]
        "index" => "sample" 
    }
stdout{
  codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

When I execute this file using logstash, I got query:

```
SELECT time, firstname, lastname, email FROM sample.sample where time > 351
```

But the `time` column is `currenttimestamp` in MySQL database which I'm tracking, and I think `sql_last_value` contains the value of this field. Am I doing something incorrect related to `sql_last_value`?

Answer (score 0):

What I was doing wrong:
we need to specify tracking_column_type if the tracking_column is not of type int. In my case, tracking_column is of type timestamp. So, I need to add:

```
tracking_column_type =>"timestamp"
```

That solved my problem.